# There is no keyword to check a if a non regular exist on robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Current implementation of keyword `File Should Exist` is using `os.path.isfile()` that returns `false` if is not a regular file. Is there a keyword to check non regular, as block or character device files?

Comment: The standard Libraries contain functionality that will cover most scenario's. If these do not meet your expectations, please have a look at the Robot Framework Userguide section on [Creating test library class or module](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a keyword. But if you can do it in Python, you can do it in RF.

Example Python function you can turn into RF keywords:

**Libraries/file-utils.py**

```py
import os, stat
from robot.utils.asserts import assert_true

def block_file_should_exist(file):
    assert_true(stat.S_ISBLK(os.stat(file).st_mode))

def character_file_should_exist(file):
    assert_true(stat.S_ISCHR(os.stat(file).st_mode))
```

and an example test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Libraries/file-utils.py    


*** Test Cases ***
Character File Exists
    Character File Should Exist    /dev/zero
```